# Access log for Exchange Server 2016

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm looking for best way to query Exchange server 2016 access logs through Powershell.

My goal is find certain IP address gained access to which mail account.

UPDATE-1:

I understood that AuditLog should be enabled for all users then wait for users to login to Exchange Server.

I found this Powershell code from Microsoft Technet that enables AuditLog for all mail accounts.

$UserMailboxes = Get-mailbox -Filter {(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox')}

$UserMailboxes | ForEach {Set-Mailbox $_.Identity -AuditEnabled $true}

Comment: Do you have any code to post? What have you tried so far.

Comment: I've tried Get-LogonStatistics but I read recently that it has been removed since Exchange Server 2013

Comment: I've found Audit log should be enabled for all mailbox users with at least  MailboxLogin in AuditOwner then wait for next logins and query log.